# sales and purchases in same MariaDB table

Tags: mysql, union

I have a vehicle table with field with date of purchase and I can retrive info with

```
SELECT
    MONTH(vehiculo.fecha_compra) mes,
    SUM(vehiculo.precio_compra) importe,
    COUNT(*) cantidad
FROM
    vehiculo
WHERE
    YEAR(vehiculo.fecha_compra) = '2024'
GROUP BY
    MONTH(vehiculo.fecha_compra);
```

[image]

And I have a second table with data about sales that can be query like:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(propuesta.fecha) mes,
    SUM(propuesta.cotizacion) importe,
    COUNT(*) cantidad
FROM
    propuesta
WHERE
    estado = "Vendido" AND YEAR(propuesta.fecha) = '2024'
GROUP BY
    MONTH(propuesta.fecha)
```

with results like:
[image]

I would have a combination between two tables to obtain something like:

[image]

Main problem is that there can be some months with purchassing but not with sales.

Comment: You need a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a full outer join. However, MySQL [still] does not implement them. You can simulate it by union-ing a left join with an anti-semi-join. You can do:

```sql
with
purchases as (
  -- first query here
),
sales as (
  -- second query here
)
select p.mes, 
  p.importe as importe_compras, p.cantidad as cantidad_compras,
  s.importe as importe_ventas, s.cantidad as cantidad_ventas
from purchases p
left join sales s on s.mes = p.mes
union all -- from here on, this includes months with sales buy no purchases
select s.mes, null, null, s.importe, s.cantidad
from sales s
left join purchases p on p.mes = s.mes
where p.mes is null
```

If there will never be months with sales an no purchases you can simplify the query by removing the tail of it (that starts with `union all`).

Comment: Thank you Impaler
That works well and give chance to study about.